# Android BLE pairing fails when connecting to a BLE dongle

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am facing a problem when I try to pair an Android 4.4.2 Smartphone to a BLE dongle which is connected to an ArchLinux OS (running on VirtualBox).

What I have done so far:

Programming an Android application (GATT server, central role) that...

1. scans for nearby devices
2. let the user select one out of the found devices
3. opens a Gatt server by calling `BluetoothManager.openGattServer(context, gattServerCallback);`
4. and finally connects to the selected device by calling `BluetoothGattServer.connect(device, false);`

To configure the BLE dongle (GATT client, peripheral role) I am using BlueZ 5.
In detail I enter following commands on the terminal:

1. `systemctl start bluetooth`
2. `hciconfig hci0 up`
3. `hciconfig hci0 leadv`

Somehow the pairing fails. Here is some snippet from LogCat:

```
 01-29 15:49:24.747: D/BluetoothGattServer(12976): connect() - device: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, auto: false
 01-29 15:49:24.747: D/BtGatt.GattService(2148): serverConnect() - address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
 01-29 15:49:29.903: D/BtGatt.GattService(2148): onConnected() connId=5, address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, connected=false
01-29 15:49:29.903: D/BluetoothGattServer(12976): onServerConnectionState() - status=0 serverIf=5 device=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

I'll add a picture of the LogCat log later when I have hopefully more than 10 reputations ;-)

Any idea why the pairing fails?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can verify the dongle end against another app, or validate your app against a known-good peripheral, that could likely save you a lot of time wondering which end of the system is failing.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to find another device but finally the app seems to work correctly since it connects successfully to a Kensington Proximo dongle- although the connection lasts only for approximately 30 sec. Consequently the problem in my original szenario is likely on the ArchLinux/Dongle side. Any idea what the problem could be?